# Switching View Controllers with Code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a game that I am trying to have go back to the main screen when you loose.  When you loose, this block of code runs, but when I uncomment the line at the end of the code it gives me an error when I try to run it.  The view controllers and classifies for the home screen and the game are different.  I couldn't find anything online that worked.

```
-(void)resetAll {
    [randomMain invalidate];

    CGRect frame = [player frame];
    frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
    frame.origin.y = 326.0;
    [player setFrame:frame];

    CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
    frame2.origin.x = 137.0f;
    frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
    [enemy setFrame:frame2];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [timerImageView stopAnimating];
    counter.text=@"";
    int sum = [lastRoundCash intValue] + [playerCash intValue];
    playerCash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
    [self performSelector:@selector(save) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabelState) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    [freezeUseOutlet setHidden:true];

    int x = [lastRoundRound floatValue];
    int y = [highScore floatValue];

    if (x>y) {
        highScore=lastRoundRound;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New High Score!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You beat your high score!  Your high score is now %@!",highScore] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabelState) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no comment line in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pop the view controller.

Comment: The error on the line is "Use of unidentified ViewController.  Pop gives the same error.

Comment: If you use pop you don't have to give it a view controller.

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewController]; Error: No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'popViewController'.  The user gets to the view controller by pressing a button linked with a simple click-drag to the controller, but I need it to switch back to the main screen without having the user push a button.

Comment: Try this: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. And you should learn to read the documentation.

Comment: Gives no errors, but doesn't make the controller disappear.  I will take a look at the documentation now.